# How do I change my Objects' local axis?

Tags: animation

I am making a robot with a lot of different connected parts that are parented to each other.. When I now wan´t to animate it they don´t rotate in the direction of it´s parent. That is makig animating very tideous so i wonder if there is a way to make them rotate around its parents´ local axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:
1: use an armature, slow to make, but makes it much easier for animation.
2: set the 3D cursor to the parents origin, right click on the child, click on, **set origin - to 3D cursor**. ( this won't work if you want the robot to rotate the children indipendently later. (not recomended for animation)
3: to rotate them, select the parts you want to rotate, with the parent selected last.  set the pivot point to **active element** and rotate them. (also not reccomended for animation.)

There are other ways to do this too, but I hope this helped.

ps, I think the armature is the best  method, but If you just want to pose your robot for a still image, the other methods will help you.